# FFmpeg progess calculation when command includes Complex Filter Graph

Tags: progress-bar, animated-gif, text-parsing, overlays

Does anyone know how to calculate the progress % from ffmpeg log of command that includes complex filter graph and .gif file as input. I have successfully calculated the progress for simple commands but Log output for complex filter graph commands is very difficult to parse, may be impossible. Here is the [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ovDI9plQ8cTjBhcjRjcEphd3M/view?usp=sharing). Any help please ....